# Can i use an AC 15A 250V / 30A 125V rocker in place of a 15A 125V / 10A 250V one?

Tags: voltage, switches, power-electronics, amperage, appliances

Amazon sent me the wrong replacement switch so i am wondering if i can use it?

Original switch is AC 15A 125V / 10A 250V
[image]

new one is AC 15A 250V / 30A 125V
[image]

can i use it without damaging the appliance?

Comment: 30A is better than 15A  at 125V ..... 15A is better than 10A at 250V ..... the new switch can handle double the current at 125V and 50% more current at 250V ..... the new switch is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use it.  The replacement is more capable than the part it is replacing. This is a good thing.

Comment: thx @Jasen I figured having bigger amps/volts meant it can handle more but I wasn't sure if the amps/volts were limits (like a fuse) and if allowing more through the switch could damage the appliance... so that is not the case then?

Comment: indeed, not the case, the switch is either a conductor or an insulator, it doesn't perform any limiting or regulating.

Comment: awesome thx @Jasen, so then the amps/volts on the label simply say how much amps/volts the switch can handle before being damaged but the fireplace should be sending less than its limits through it since the old, more limited, one worked fine?

Comment: that's it exactly.